# список в словарь, python

Tags: python, dict

возникли трудности с преобразованием списка в словарь. Нужно из простого списка составить словарь с ключами 0,1,2,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вот это наверное самый короткий и простой способ:

```
arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']

res = dict(enumerate(arr))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно

```
dd={}
for i in range(len(lst)):
    dd[i]=lst[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно, к примеру, так:

```
arr = [1, 20, 300]
d = {i: arr[i] for i in range(len(arr))}
```